# I need help converting JSON data into a 3 level multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I need help converting JSON data into a 3 level multidimensional array in javascript. My code that I an retrieving in JSON format looks like this:

```
[
 {'City':'Philadelphia','State':'Pennsylvania','Country':'United States'},
 {'City':'Pittsburgh','State':'Pennsylvania','Country':'United States'}, 
 {'City':'Harrisburg','State':'Pennsylvania', 'Country':'United States'}, 
 {'City':'Sacramento', 'State':'California', 'Country':'United States'}, 
 {'City':'Fremont', 'State':'California', 'Country':'United States'}, 
 {'City':'Los Angeles', 'State':'California','Country': 'United States'}, 
 {'City':'Sydney', 'State':'New South Wales', 'Country':'Australia'}, 
 {'City':'Melbourne', 'State':'Victoria', 'Country':'Australia'}
]
```

But I need it in this format:

```
$scope.countries = {
    'United States': 
    {
       'Pennsylvania': ['Philadelphia', 'Pittsburgh', 'Harrisburg'],
       'California': ['Sacramento', 'Fremont', 'Los Angeles']
    },
    'Australia': 
    {
       'New South Wales': ['Sydney'],
       'Victoria': ['Melbourne']
    }
};
```

Comment: Where do you get the original JSON String from. Do you generate it somehow or do you get it from somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah, that's some weird looking JSON data. It's not even valid actually, you can't have an object that has no value for its keys.

Comment: Jon Koops is 100% right about that being completely invalid JSON.  It's ALWAYS best if you can get the data in the format that you need it.

Comment: I believe it's `[[]]` and not `[{}]`?

Comment: @Konkko either would be valid depending on requirements. Array of objects, or array of arrays. Array of objects [{}] is very common especially when using angular which it would seem this person is (guessing by use of $scope. )

Comment: @Doug regardless, the objects in the array still need to be key value pairs.  the array of objects above is invalid.  would throw an error.

Comment: Oh I never disputed that  only helping konkko.

Comment: @Doug I meant that it didn't have the keys, only values. Thats why it was odd

Answer (score 1):

So it would look something like this to give you the JSON you want

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nx4hrAex8JCCbnYG5X3t?p=preview

## EDIT

Edited to work with the new format.

```
var original =  [
 {'City':'Philadelphia','State':'Pennsylvania','Country':'United States'},
 {'City':'Pittsburgh','State':'Pennsylvania','Country':'United States'}, 
 {'City':'Harrisburg','State':'Pennsylvania', 'Country':'United States'}, 
 {'City':'Sacramento', 'State':'California', 'Country':'United States'}, 
 {'City':'Fremont', 'State':'California', 'Country':'United States'}, 
 {'City':'Los Angeles', 'State':'California','Country': 'United States'}, 
 {'City':'Sydney', 'State':'New South Wales', 'Country':'Australia'}, 
 {'City':'Melbourne', 'State':'Victoria', 'Country':'Australia'}
]
  var json = {};
  for(var i in original){
    var country = original[i].Country; 
    var state = original[i].State;
    var city = original[i].City;
    var obj = {};
    
    if(!json.hasOwnProperty(country)){
      obj[state] = [city];
      json[country] = obj;
    }
    else if(json[country].hasOwnProperty(state)){
      json[country][state].push(city);
    }
    else if(!json[country].hasOwnProperty(state)){
      json[country][state] = [city];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you change how your data comes through.  That being said, in the off chance that you meant to type array brackets instead of object brackets, I have provided a JSBin solution to your question.

https://jsbin.com/qaxubigija/edit?js,console

```
function dataParse() {

  var data = [
    [ 'Philadelphia','Pennsylvania','United States'],    
    ['Pittsburgh','Pennsylvania','United States'], 
    ['Harrisburg','Pennsylvania', 'United States'], 
    ['Sacramento', 'California', 'United States'], 
    ['Fremont', 'California', 'United States'], 
    ['Los Angeles', 'California', 'United States'], 
    ['Sydney', 'New South Wales', 'Australia'], 
    ['Melbourne', 'Victoria', 'Australia']
  ];

  var newObject = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    // create your references
    var currentNode = data[i],
        city = currentNode[0],
        state = currentNode[1],
        country = currentNode[2];

    // check that the country property exists
    // create if it does not exist
    if( typeof newObject[country] == 'undefined'){
      newObject[country] = {};
    }

    // check that the state property exists
    // create if it does not exist
    if( typeof newObject[country][state] == 'undefined'){
      newObject[country][state] = [];
    }    

    // push city to the proper array
    newObject[country][state].push(city);

  }

  console.log(newObject);

}

dataParse();
```

Comment: I'm sorry there are keys. I was typing from memory. I edited the post. But no it's [{ to start the son data. I'm using php json_encode function. It is from a database

Comment: Thank you so much for this.